# Python Soc Network Analysis: Calculating 'Chance Network Homophily' by iterating through a list, using a function

Tags: python, math, probability, social-networking

I am hoping to plug items into an equation **from any list** of dictionary values. The equation is to calculate homophily.

### **Background:**

Homophily: the probability that different characteristics will be shared within a social network. For example, the probability of people in a sample population sharing an eye colour.

This is how the equation might work in that example:

**(frequency of blue eyes / sum frequency)^2 + (frequency brown eyes / sum frequency)^2**

Bear in mind, this would have to work even if you had more than two characteristics (green, hazel, gray). But, I'm keeping it simple to make it easy to check the result.

So if we had this data in the form of a dictionary:

```
EYES = {'Kevin':'brown', 'Frank':'blue', 'Alex':'blue', 'Tracey':'brown', 'Milo':'blue'}
```

First I calculate frequency of values in the dictionary, like this:

```
def frequency(EYES):
    Eyes_freq_dict = Counter(EYES.values())
    return Eyes_freq_dict

Counter({'blue': 3, 'brown': 2})
```

Now I have a second dictionary of the frequencies alone to work with:

```
 Counter({'blue': 3, 'brown': 2})
```

But because dictionaries are unordered, I must put the values into a format that I can do maths on.

I think this **needs** to be a list? Please correct me if I'm wrong:

```
Eyes_freq_dict = frequency(EYES)
EYESlist = []
for v in Eyes_freq_dict.values():
    EYESlist.append(v)
```

I then get the values on their own, as a list:
    EYESlist
    [3, 2]

### **Stumbling block:**

I am new to doing maths with Python, so I am now worried that I might have reached a dead end. Is it actually possible for me to plug these components into the above equation?

The desired equation in this case would be:

**(EYESlist[0]/ sum(EYESlist))^2 + (EYESlist[1])/sum(EYESlist))^2**

Or in English, it works out to:

**3/5 squared + 2/5 squared = 0.52 **

The problem now is: How to iterate over, firstly, this list. And then ANY list (of any length) to get a correct result.

If the route I'm taking is a dud, please be kind but do let me know! I'd be happy if there is a more elegant way of solving this, but I hope it's fun exploring.

Just trying to type up the formula and test it in a pythonic way, I'm confused because I'm getting an error message:

```
 sum(((EYESlist[0]/ sum(EYESlist))**2)((EYESlist[1])/ sum(EYESlist))**2)
#TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

I hope somebody can point me in the right direction! I'd like to get on with the REST of my homework (I have five other problems to work through).

What I will probably do if I can't resolve this quickly, is move onto other questions and then come back to this one. It is an interesting challenge for me.

Best,
A

Comment: This boils down to "Have you tried it?" Have you tried entering your equation exactly as you typed it here? What was the result? You say you're new to doing maths in python, and the best way to learn what works and what doesn't is to try it. For reference, the quation should be fine the way you have it. (Though `sum(li[0:])` is equivalent to `sum(li)` to be more pythonic, and you shouldn't name a `dict` "dict" as this can shadow the built in object or method)

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but it didn't do anything... might be a formatting issue on my side. Glad that you think this is on the right track.

Comment: One other hint I missed before. Likely the only error (other than a missing parenthesis) in what you're trying is that exponents in python are not `2^2==4`, rather `2**2==4`

Comment: I've just edited the question to show the error message I'm getting now. Thanks for the pointers! If I remain really stuck then I might move on to other problems, and come back to this later on. ... Context is, I'm working on this alongside looking after a 1yo, so I hope I can sustain the effort for long enough to figure it out. This is only the first homework question of five that I'm doing!! But I'm finding this very interesting.

Comment: It's tough working on it a little at a time, I feel your pain. The best thing to do is to work through the equation the same way you would a program,a piece at a a time. For example, get `percent_blue=(EYESlist[0]/ sum(EYESlist))`, then add a step, then another, and see where your errors happen. Since this is a homework problem, I won't write it out for you, but currently I see an issue with the equation, remember that `(1)(2)` is not the same as `(1)*(2)` in code

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation, The problem is very clear and is pretty much done.

The **Use of lists is accurate** and is easy to deal with although a more efficient way is somewhere out there.

We could convert the Counter object given by the `frequency()` to list explicitly 
using

```py
EYEScounter = frequency(EYES)
EYESlist = list(EYEScounter.values())
```

As we need to iterate with *each and every value* of the list to calculate the **Chance homophily**.

```py
def chance_homophily(EYESlist):
    chance_homophily = 0
    for color_count in EYESlist:
        chance_homophily += (color_count/sum(EYESlist))**2
    return chance_homophily
```

Calling the function with the list of values returns the `chance_homophily` directly **regardless of the number of eye colors you take**.

```py
print(chance_homophily(EYESlist))
```

Output:

```
0.52
```