# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list using Counter

Tags: python, typeerror

I have got an error due to Counter apply to a dict.
My dict looks like this

```
{'Dan': [nan,
  nan,
  'No results',
  'No results',
  1,
  1,
  'Dan_final.csv',
  1.0],
 'Matt': ['Greg',
  2.9,
  'No results',
  'No results',
  1,
  1,
  'Matt_final.csv',
  1.0]}
```

and it was created from a dataframe:

```
df_dict=df.set_index('n1').T.to_dict('list')
```

I am trying to use the below code:

```
def frequency(EYES):
    Eyes_freq_dict = Counter(EYES.values())
    return Eyes_freq_dict

EYEScounter = frequency(df_dict)
EYESlist = list(EYEScounter.values())
```

function which comes from [Python Soc Network Analysis: Calculating 'Chance Network Homophily' by iterating through a list, using a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54204106/python-soc-network-analysis-calculating-chance-network-homophily-by-iterating)

The error is `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`
I have tried to use `Counter(map(tuple(EYES.values())))` but it has not worked.
Do you know how I can fix this error?
I need the frequency to get the chance homophily function as in the question I mentioned above.

Comment: Question: what's your expected output from `frequency(df_dict)`? e.g. in the linked question the output is `Counter({'blue': 3, 'brown': 2})`

Comment: I was referring to the function rather than the output, adding it as reference since the function was from there. The user 9mjb has answered my question, fixing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data structure... {'Dan': [nan,[...]
But lists can't be the keys of a dict, which is what Counter does.
So change them (if you are not modifying them) to tuples...

```
>>> Counter([ 1,2,3,1,2,1])
Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1})
>>> Counter([ [],1,2,3,1,2,1]) # [] can't be a key
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> Counter([ (),1,2,3,1,2,1]) # but () is ok
Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, (): 1, 3: 1})
```

So... you could convert those lists to tuples...

```
Eyes_freq_dict = Counter(EYES.values())
```

change to

```
Eyes_freq_dict = Counter([tuple(x) for x in EYES.values()])
```

This changes each element in the list of values into tuples (which are ok as keys to a dict, which is what Counter() is trying to do).